# Removal of elements during iteration through a list - safety

Tags: c++, iteration

I was wondering if something like this is safe...

```
// Iterating through a <list>
while ( iter != seq.end()) {
  if ( test ) {
    iter = seq.erase( iter );
  } else {
    ++iter;
 }
```

I know that iterating through a vector in this way would invalidate the iterator, but would the same thing occur in a list? I assume not since a list is sequential through pointers rather than being "next" to each other in memory, but any reassurance would be helpful.

Comment: Note: That is also valid with std::vector, all existing iterators into the vector will be invalidated, but the iterator returned by the `erase` method is a valid iterator.

Comment: Right, but by safe I mean continued operations on the container will be fine as other iterators won't be invalidated ( in this case, besides the one erased ).

Comment: If you have *other* iterators, you'd better make sure they can't possibly be pointing to the element that just got erased...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is just fine because the erase method returns a new valid iterator.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the standard way to do that. See Effective STL, Item 9 (p. 46).

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- `std::list::erase()`: "Invalidates only the iterators and references to the erased elements."

That said, you *probably* shouldn't do this at all -- you seem to be trying to imitate `std::remove_if()`.

Comment: Why not std::list::remove_if: http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/list/remove_if?

Answer (score 1):

The standard defines `erase` behaviour for every STL container. For `std::list` only iterators to the erased elements are invalidated. The return value of `erase` needn't be a dereferencable one, though (it could be `list.end()`).

Therefore, to erase all elements in a list the following is absolutely valid:

```
.. it = l.begin();
while(it != l.end()) {
   it = l.erase(it);
}
```

BUT beware of something like this (dangerous pitfall):

```
for (.. it  = l.begin; it != l.end(); ++it) {
      it = l.erase(it);
   }
```

If it is `l.end()`, it is incremented twice (second time by the loop head). Baamm.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is totally safe.  The `erase()` function returns an iterator to the element succeeding the one which was erased.  Had you not reassigned the result of `erase()` to `iter`, you'd have trouble.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, your code does not invalidate the iterator used in the function. However, it *does* invalidate *other* iterators if the collection is a vector, but not if the collection is a list.

Comment: It may invalidate *other* iterators even if the collection is a list, provided the *other* iterators point to the erased element.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, yes, it will work. But I'd recommend using [list::remove_if](http://www.cppreference.com/wiki/stl/list/remove_if) instead, as it's more expressive.